# Content-Type header [application/x-www-form-urlencoded] is not supported on Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, curl, mime-types, content-type, http-put

I used to have ElasticSearch 5.2, and just upgraded to 6.0.

I am trying to create an index template following guide [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-templates.html), but got error

```
Content-Type header [application/x-www-form-urlencoded] is not supported
```

My query is

```
curl -X PUT localhost:9200/_template/template_1 -d '
{
  "index_patterns": ["te*", "bar*"],
  "mappings": {
    "type1": {
      "properties": {
        "host_name": {
          "type": "keyword"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

Answer (score 313, accepted):

To fix this, add curl option `-H 'Content-Type: application/json'`

---

This error is due to **strict content-type checking** introduced in ElasticSearch 6.0, as explained in [this post](https://www.elastic.co/blog/strict-content-type-checking-for-elasticsearch-rest-requests)

> Starting from Elasticsearch 6.0, all REST requests that include a body must also provide the correct content-type for that body.

Comment: Hi @sam, Is there any permanent solution so that I don't have to give this flag for each request.

Comment: @sam thanks sam however when I add curl option it give me {"error":"Content-Type header [application/x-www-form-urlencoded] is not supported","status":406}curl: (6) Could not resolve host: application

Comment: @haneulkim If running curl on Windows, you need to use double quote character instead of single quote. Here is example curl command on Windows: curl -X PUT "localhost:9200/customer/_doc/1?pretty" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d" {\"name\": \"John Doe\"}"

Answer (score 20):

The solution is to add `Content-Type: application/json` header

```
curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/_template/template_1' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -d '**your query**'
```

Answer (score 5):

```
"{ \"name\": { \"first\": {} }, \"address\": [ { \"address1\":\"lane\" } ] } "
```

In Windows, when you give JSON as a parameter, use double quotes only. Use escape character.

Comment: Thanks, this was really helpful