# ElasticSearch :content-type header application/x-www-form-urlencoded is not supported

Tags: elasticsearch, curl

So i had this error after typing this command:
`curl -XPUT localhost:9200/_bulk --data-binary @movies_elastic.json`, i found an answer here : [ElasticSearch - Content-Type header [application/x-www-form-urlencoded] is not supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47544966/elasticsearch-content-type-header-application-x-www-form-urlencoded-is-not-s)
that suggested to add -H option but i didn't get where to add it exactly.
Please keep in mind i'm new to ELK.
Thanks.

[screenshot from console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXTZs.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ElasticSearch - Content-Type header \[application/x-www-form-urlencoded\] is not supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47544966/elasticsearch-content-type-header-application-x-www-form-urlencoded-is-not-s)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming everything else with your command is correct, it's a command line option to curl. Like this:

```
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/_bulk -H'Content-Type: application/json' --data-binary @movies_elastic.json
```