# CURL : Content-Type header [application/x-www-form-urlencoded] is not supported

Tags: elasticsearch, curl

Working on ElasticSearch and trying some queries for creating index, posting  data using the curl.

Using the curl provided by GIT(Windows GIT)

The command goes to add a document to a index named customer.

The curl command from the ElasticSearch site it is copied as below :

```
curl -X PUT "localhost:9200/customer/_doc/1?pretty" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
  "name": "John Doe"
}
'
```

The above command does not work for me. I just make it a single line as below

```
curl -X PUT "localhost:9200/customer/_doc/1?pretty" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"name": "John Doe"}'
```

I get the below error.

[image: Please refer the screenshot.]

Other command like creating an index run like below

```
curl -X PUT "localhost:9200/customer?pretty"

Response is :

{
      "acknowledged" : true,
      "shards_acknowledged" : true,
      "index" : "customer"
    }
```

The curl command having the json as content are not working.

Already referred the below link but could not get it 
[Content Type Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47544966/elasticsearch-content-type-header-application-x-www-form-urlencoded-is-not-s)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

On Windows, you need to use double quotes and escape the ones in the content:

```
curl -X PUT "localhost:9200/customer/_doc/1?pretty" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{\"name\": \"John Doe\"}"
```

Alternatively, you can store the content in a file called data.json

```
{"name": "John Doe"}
```

And then send it via curl like this so you don't have to escape the double quotes:

```
curl -X PUT "localhost:9200/customer/_doc/1?pretty" -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data-binary @data.json
```