# how to GET json query results from Windows command terminal

Tags: json, elasticsearch, command, kibana

I have a json query that I am trying to pass through the command line

I have tried replacing outer single quotes with double quotes, but still shows me error

```
curl -XGET "http://localhost:9200/honda/_search?pretty" -H 'Content-Type: 
application/json' -d “@{“query”:{"match":{"color":"silver"}}}”
```

Expected: Documents that matches field:silver
Actual Error: Warning: 
    Couldn't read data from file "", this makes an empty POST

```
THEN DISPLAYS MY ALL MY DOCUMENTS:

    {
    "_index" : "honda",
    "_type" : "_doc",
    "_id" : "234",
    "_score" : 1.0,
    "_source" : {
      "model" : "Accord EX",
      "price" : 28000,
      "color" : "red",
      "num_doors" : 4,
      "weight" : "9000lbs"
    }
  }.................................
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: application
{"query":{"match":{"color":"silver"}}}"
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
```

Comment: this answer should help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53928390/4604579

Answer (score 0):

Try escaping the characters for quotes.