# adding snapshot to elasticsearch Windows

Tags: elasticsearch

I have two snapshots that I want to insert into elasticsearch in path:

```
C:\Users\name\Downloads\book_backup\agg_example
C:\Users\name\Downloads\book_backup\search_example
```

which I properly listed in elasticsearch.yml

```
path.repo: ["C:\\Users\\olulo\\Downloads\\book_backup\\agg_example", "C:\\Users\\olulo\\Downloads\\book_backup\\search_example"]
```

my elasticsearch starts fine and creating a new index works too.

Now when I try to insert snapshot into my elasticsearch so I can work on it:

```
curl -XPUT "http://localhost:9200/movies/" -d '{"type":"fs", "settings":{"location":"C:\\Users\\name\\Downloads\\book_backup\\search_example", "compress":true}}'
```

It gives me:

```
curl: (1) Protocol "'http" not supported or disabled in libcurl
curl: (3) [globbing] unmatched brace in column 10
curl: (3) [globbing] unmatched close brace/bracket in column 14
```

In https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.2/modules-snapshots.html it seems like they've added a name at the end of path in location so I did

```
curl -XPUT "http://localhost:9200/movies/" -d '{"type":"fs", "settings":{"location":"C:\\Users\\name\\Downloads\\book_backup\\search_example\\test", "compress":true}}'
```

but still gives me same error.

following https://superuser.com/questions/1322567/http-not-supported-or-disabled-in-libcurl I've change everything to double quotes:

```
 curl -XPUT "http://localhost:9200/_snapshot/javacafe" -d "{"type":"fs", "settings":{"location":"C:\\Users\\olulo\\Downloads\\book_backup\\search_example", "compress":true}}"
```

giving me :

```
{"error":"Content-Type header [application/x-www-form-urlencoded] is not supported","status":406}
```

Tried adding curl option as suggested [Content-Type header [application/x-www-form-urlencoded] is not supported on Elasticsearch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47544966/content-type-header-application-x-www-form-urlencoded-is-not-supported-on-elas) by

```
    curl -XPUT "localhost:9200/_snapshot/javacafe" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d "{
    "type":"fs",
     "settings"{"location":"C:\\Users\\olulo\\Downloads\\book_backup\\search_example\\test", "compress":true}
}"
```

which outputs similar error with added statement at the end:

```
{"error":"Content-Type header [application/x-www-form-urlencoded] is not supported","status":406}curl: (6) Could not resolve host: application
```

**SOLVED :** for windows you need to use backslash infront of double quotation mark inside {}:

```
    curl -XPUT "localhost:9200/_snapshot/javacafe" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{
    \"type\":\"fs\",
     \"settings\"{\"location\":"C:\\Users\\olulo\\Downloads\\book_backup\\search_example\\test", \"compress\":true}
}"
```

From my understanding windows use \ to consider " as it is. If so why not add backslash to all curl commands as well?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
curl -XPUT "localhost:9200/_snapshot/javacafe" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{
"type":"fs",
 "settings" : {
   "location":"C:\\Users\\olulo\\Downloads\\book_backup\\search_example\\test",
   "compress":true
  }
}'
```