# How could we insert a document into Elastic Search?‽‽?

Tags: string, elasticsearch, cmd

I am following the tutorial:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/getting-started-index.html

When I copy the command to insert a document, and then I paste it into windows cmd, we see the following:

```
C:\Users\ymorenoj\Downloads\elasticsearch-7.5.2-windows-x86_64\elasticsearch-7.5.2\bin>curl -X PUT "localhost:9200/customer/_doc/1?pretty" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
  "error" : "Content-Type header [application/x-www-form-urlencoded] is not supported",
  "status" : 406
}
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: application

C:\Users\ymorenoj\Downloads\elasticsearch-7.5.2-windows-x86_64\elasticsearch-7.5.2\bin>{
"{" no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo,
programa o archivo por lotes ejecutable.

C:\Users\ymorenoj\Downloads\elasticsearch-7.5.2-windows-x86_64\elasticsearch-7.5.2\bin>  "name": "John Doe"
""name":" no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo,
programa o archivo por lotes ejecutable.

C:\Users\ymorenoj\Downloads\elasticsearch-7.5.2-windows-x86_64\elasticsearch-7.5.2\bin>}
"}" no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo,
programa o archivo por lotes ejecutable.

C:\Users\ymorenoj\Downloads\elasticsearch-7.5.2-windows-x86_64\elasticsearch-7.5.2\bin>'
"'" no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo,
programa o archivo por lotes ejecutable.
```

So then I edited the command to fit it into one line as:

```
curl -XPUT "localhost:9200/customer/_doc/1?pretty" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"name":"John Doe"}'
```

And when we execute it, the cmd outputs:

```
C:\Users\ymorenoj\Downloads\elasticsearch-7.5.2-windows-x86_64\elasticsearch-7.5.2\bin>curl -XPUT "localhost:9200/customer/_doc/1?pretty" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"name":"John Doe"}'
{
  "error" : "Content-Type header [application/x-www-form-urlencoded] is not supported",
  "status" : 406
}
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: application
```

I read:

[Content-Type header [application/x-www-form-urlencoded] is not supported on Elasticsearch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47544966/content-type-header-application-x-www-form-urlencoded-is-not-supported-on-elas)

And I checked that I have already written: `-H 'Content-Type: application/json'`

Besides I read:

[Content-Type header [application/x-www-form-urlencoded] is not supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48209323/content-type-header-application-x-www-form-urlencoded-is-not-supported?noredirect=1&lq=1)

And I tried to put double quotes around localhost and content-type:

```
curl -XPUT "localhost:9200/customer/_doc/1?pretty" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"name":"John Doe"}'
```

After executing it we observe:

```
C:\Users\ymorenoj\Downloads\elasticsearch-7.5.2-windows-x86_64\elasticsearch-7.5.2\bin>curl -XPUT "localhost:9200/customer/_doc/1?pretty" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"name":"John Doe"}'
{
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [
      {
        "type" : "not_x_content_exception",
        "reason" : "not_x_content_exception: Compressor detection can only be called on some xcontent bytes or compressed xcontent bytes"
      }
    ],
    "type" : "mapper_parsing_exception",
    "reason" : "failed to parse",
    "caused_by" : {
      "type" : "not_x_content_exception",
      "reason" : "not_x_content_exception: Compressor detection can only be called on some xcontent bytes or compressed xcontent bytes"
    }
  },
  "status" : 400
}
```

In addition I have tried to replace both quotes with single quotes, and then here we have our cmd trace:

```
C:\Users\ymorenoj\Downloads\elasticsearch-7.5.2-windows-x86_64\elasticsearch-7.5.2\bin>curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/customer/_doc/1?pretty' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"name":"John Doe"}'
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: 'localhost
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: application
```

Plus to check we do have Elastic Search up and running:

```
C:\Users\ymorenoj\Downloads\elasticsearch-7.5.2-windows-x86_64\elasticsearch-7.5.2\bin>curl -X GET "localhost:9200/_cat/health?v&pretty"
epoch      timestamp cluster       status node.total node.data shards pri relo init unassign pending_tasks max_task_wait_time active_shards_percent
1580922144 17:02:24  elasticsearch green           2         2      2   1    0    0        0             0                  -                100.0%
```

How could we solve this?‽‽?

Comment: if you are using mac. you can use postman to insert new document

Answer (score 1):

hah, windows and curl can be cumbersome...

in windows, this version work:

```
curl -XPUT "localhost:9200/customer/_doc/1?pretty" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{""name"":""John Doe""}"
```

Please note the double quotes inside the json.

If you're working under windows, try the Windows Linux Subsystem (WSL) or Cygwin. This will help you a lot. Another option is to install kibana and use the dev tools

Comment: +1 for Console in the Dev Tools. Will save you not only from this problem but remove the repetitive parts plus autocompletion and syntax highlighting.